# Getting BPM from file with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

Is there anybody who can help? I'm building an audio player with HTML5 Audio API. How do I get Javascript to return to me the bpm of the file? I'm **NOT** talking about **calculating** the bpm, I'm talking about accessing and returning the bpm stored in the file.

Comment: Can you show us what code you've tried so far?

Comment: What file types are you talking about?

Comment: I'm talking about mp3 files.

Answer (score 0):

Use a reader to read ID3v2 tags, for example if you need it in Javascript you can use https://github.com/aadsm/JavaScript-ID3-Reader